# Assemblies refer to the same metadata but only one is a linked reference; consider removing one of the references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am currently dealing with the error word for word:

`Assemblies 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\AudioFileSorter\AudioFileSorter\obj\Debug\Interop.QTOControlLib.dll' and 'C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\AudioFileSorter\AudioFileSorter\libs\Interop.QTOControlLib.dll' refer to the same metadata but only one is a linked reference (specified using /link option); consider removing one of the references.`

My references include several files:

```
AxInterop.QTOControlLib.dll
Interop.QTOControlLib.dll
Interop.QTOLibrary.dll
Interop.Shell32.dll
taglib-sharp.dll
```

These files are all located and referenced from a folder called `libs` within the base location for my project: `AudioFileSorter\AudioFileSorter\libs\`

An additional control reference was included as the Apple QuickTime Control 2.0 from the COM references. With the exception of this reference all other references were added by right clicking 'References' in the Solution Explorer and clicking 'Add Reference' and then browsing the libs folder to pull dll file.

Obviously, I have no idea what I am doing and I don't know how to solve it. The project worked fine yesterday and after trying to build the project to a release build everything got messed up and now I have this error. I have tried removing one of the duplicate references but then i end up just missing the reference when the app calls it during this code line:

```
private void SortM4PFiles(string[] files)
{
    WriteLine("Begin compiling .m4p files...");
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
         axQTControl1.URL = file;

         // Create new movie object
         QTOLibrary.QTMovie mov = new QTOLibrary.QTMovie();
         mov = axQTControl1.Movie;

         string title = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationFullName];
         string artist = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationArtist];
         string album = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationAlbum];
         songs.Add(new Song(title, album, artist, file));
         songs[songs.Count - 1].setType(".m4p");
            WriteLine("Evaluated " + title);
     }

     // Make sure the previous .m4p is not in use
     // This will prevent an IOException when the file is in use and cannot be moved
     axQTControl1.URL = "";
}
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[This was the tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50056/Read-M4A-tags-in-C) for using the QuickTime control and reading m4p and m4a metadata.

Comment: You'll have to chose between using the interop libraries directly *or* adding the COM reference.  The latter is almost always the better choice since you can be sure that it is at least the correct reference on your machine.  Do keep in mind that Apple discontinued QuickTime for Windows and that's not because it ever worked well.  You never want to install [virus bait](http://blog.trendmicro.com/urgent-call-action-uninstall-quicktime-windows-today/) on your user's machine.  There are better ways to play back media, consider WMP.

Comment: @HansPassant unfortuantely I'm not trying to play media, I'm trying to get the metadata from m4p and m4a files and I'm not sure how to do that without any other tool...

Comment: @HansPassant I had the same error but couldn't figure it out after half an hour of deleting and adding COM references. I kept coming back to analyzing your comment 'you must choose' above since I know you're very knowledgeable. Eventually, I figured out that if it wasn't my COM references it must be some other reference area. And I eventually found it under Assemblies in my NET 5 project (sigh). Thank you for the precision in your comment.

Comment: I had the same issue. There is an option in VStudio > References > Properties > AxInterop.WMPLib must be set EmbedInteropTypes = False and ..> WMPLib: EmbedInteropTypes = Make sure both dll lie in the Build/ Release folder!! WIth VS2017 you need to copy it manually after build

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to convert one project from packages.config to PackageReference... & I got this issue. After looking into it, I realized that, there are two references added for the same dll.

How? One from nuget & one from local COM dll. I had remove one reference to fix the issue.
[image]